# Software to select portion of screen, and click

Tags: mouse, keyboard, accessibility

Some time ago I saw software running on either a Mac or a Linux desktop which enabled full keyboard control of mouse-centric GUIs. The user could press a hotkey which **divides the screen into sections**, and the user would narrow down the section of the screen using the keyboard. By bisecting the X and Y coordinates on the screen the user could easily click on any place on the screen.

I am looking for such software for either Linux or Mac OS-X, as I use both operating systems.

I am *not* referring to [Mouse Keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_keys), in which the user must push the mouse in the required direction with the keyboard.

Comment: Sounds like an extremely long winded way to do it. Wouldn't a macro recorder be more helpful? Or a scripting language?

Comment: @Mawg: Actually one can bisect most GUI windows in very few keystrokes, and with some practice preemptively know which keypress combinations will bring us to the proper part of the screen. VIM users are great at that!

Answer (score 2):

## FOUND IT!

#### [Keynav](https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/keynav/): Retire your mouse (C, X11)

Keynav is a piece of an on-going experiment to make pointer-driven interfaces easier and faster for users to operate. It lets you move the pointer quickly to most points on the screen with only a few key strokes.

[image: Keynav screenshot]

## But what about the Mac?

**[XEasyMotion](https://github.com/dotancohen/XEasyMotion)**: Using keyboard control mouse on MacOS ( OS X ), like keynav.

[image: XEasyMotion screenshot]

**[QuickMouse](https://github.com/trishume/QuickMouse)**: O(log9(N)) keyboard mouse for OSX that uses the Numpad.

[image: QuickMouse screenshot]